# Mod 6 counter that counts 1-6 on a 7 segment display (FIXED)

Tags: circuit-analysis, digital-logic, counter, decoder

I fixed the problem, thank you all for your help, I posted the entire circuit, for anyone in the future who has a similar problem.
[image]
[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Comment: One major problem is that you're connecting all sorts of outputs together, which is not going to work. You also need resistors between your 7 segment LED and the 7447.

Comment: I'd suggest you bye a counter IC (such as 74LS161 - it's actually a four bit counter but you can make it work on mode 6) and a 74LS90 to convert the binary coded number to decimal and display it on the 7-seg. No one implements such circuits when easier and cheaper solutions exist.

Comment: I'm not planning on making this into an actual circuit, it's just for my school, as a simulation, I'm very good at making these circuits on paper, but in simulations I fail so hard, my biggest questions are how to reset the counter and how to make all this stuff work automatically, manually is easier imo as there are already plenty videos of it on youtube, nobody actually does it automatically which sucks.

As a 3-bit counter I used numbers 1,3,5,7,2,6 and then the forbidden states are 0 and 4, and as decoder I just ignored 0 and 7 and placed them as X

Comment: "I'm very good at making these circuits on paper, but in simulations I fail so hard" Sorry, but the second part of that statement rather negates the first.

Comment: Also it seems there's no output pin connected to the net of the "top" pin of gate U8.

Comment: @MichaelScofield: I don't think you've got the hang of this site yet. Now you've posted a solution but there is no problem. Future readers won't know what problem this solves. In addition all the answers below now look stupid because they are answering a question that has been deleted. You can roll back your edit and add the new stuff as an update. Alternatively post the solution as an answer and mark it accepted so it will float to the top and readers will understand the problem and the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm note sure why you are trying to override the outputs of the 7447N. If it were a CMOS design, doing so would burn current and potentially likely parts. You could simply connect the outputs of your flops directly to inputs of the 7447N. Your logic should drive the inputs of the flops.

A K-map of your logic should looks something like below. Note I using D-flipflops instead of JK-flipflops; you will need to adjust if you must use JKs. I also merged three K-maps into one and color coded them. There are two illegal states (0 and 7), they can be any legal state value that can make the logic easier (or whatever your recovery rules are).

$$
\begin{array}{lc|cccc} \
\rlap{D_{\color{red}{2},\color{blue}{1},\color{green}{0}}} && \rlap{Q_1Q_0} \\
   &    & 00 & 01 & 11 & 10 \\\hline
Q_2 & 0 & \color{red}{x}\color{blue}{x}\color{green}{x}^\ast & \color{red}{0}\color{blue}{1}\color{green}{0} & \color{red}{1}\color{blue}{0}\color{green}{0} & \color{red}{0}\color{blue}{1}\color{green}{1} \\
   & 1 & \color{red}{1}\color{blue}{0}\color{green}{1} & \color{red}{1}\color{blue}{1}\color{green}{0} & \color{red}{x}\color{blue}{x}\color{green}{x}^\ast & \color{red}{0}\color{blue}{0}\color{green}{1}
\end{array} \\
^\ast \text{ illegal $Q$, recover}
$$

Now figure out the next states. To ensure I'm not doing your homework, the equations are intentionally incomplete. If finding the groups from from a triple variable is challenging, split into seperate k-maps (one for red entries, anther blue, then green).

$$
\begin{align}
\color{red}{D_2} & = Q_2\overline{Q_1} + \cdots_\color{red}{\text{(other red groupings)}} \\
\color{blue}{D_1} & = \overline{Q_1}Q_0 + \cdots_\color{blue}{\text{(other blue groupings)}} \\
\color{green}{D_0} & = \overline{Q_0} + \cdots_\color{green}{\text{(other green groupings)}} \\
\end{align}
$$

Depending on which technology you are using, you may need to add some pull-up or pull-down resisters. The datasheet I was looking at shows the output if the 7447 would need pull-up resisters on each output; your's might be different.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I think I understand what you mean,I've learned all this on Bosnian so some things I can't really translate or understand but I'm trying my best, I know how to use all 5 bistables and I have added the picture of how I think this is solved, what I'm not sure is if I should go C-B-A and not A-B-C, since C is the most important bit.

Comment: I have successfully made a counter and I banned number 7. So now it counts from 0-6, how do I ban the 0 ?

Comment: Your updated question looks much better. Be aware the set pins on the flop need to be connected to ground or some other logic. The 0 should only happen initially; it will self resolve (eg: 0-6,1-6,1-6,...). To completely remove the 0, there are two ways to go about it. Add a reset/preset logic (synchronous or asynchronous) to get the flops into 001. Or use the next state logic as the input to the 7447. Note if it must start at 1, then next_state must be 001 when current state is 000. FYI: your \$D_C\$ can be simplified

Comment: Hello I've updated my project, and since I don't have to use a 7 seg display , I won't. This is my 3rd grade high school project and I'm quite a rookie so you could you look at the post again and help me solve this (or these) last problem/s.

Answer (score 0):

As @dirac16 pointed out in the OP comments, this circuit is trivial if you use the appropriate ICs. Something like this would meet your requirements:

[image: 1-6 counter]
*sorry for the crude schematic - I had to do it on my phone*

- The counter is set to preload a b’1 when the load pin is signaled
- The two AND gates watch for a b’7 to create the load signal, essentially resetting the count back to b’1
- The OR gate is only necessary to protect against out-of-bounds values which may occur when the circuit is first powered up
- The weird blue circle is the symbol that EveryCircuit chose for the digital clock

A [74LS161](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn54ls161a.pdf) would work perfectly for this.

That’s all there is to it. Assuming you can’t base your circuit on this chip, I would suggest you just study the logic diagram in its datasheet, and mimic it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the reason i'm using trivial components is because thats my project, I need to make 1-6 counter using logic gates and probes, thank you for your simplified version but I cant explain it to the professor, i'm still in 3rd grade, so i'll stick to basic components, if you know how to solve this problem with these components, then any advice is helpful

Comment: The circuit for the chip on the left is on page 7 of the link I provided. The circuit for the chip on the right can be found in the 74LS49 datasheet. Combine all this and you’re done. Keep in mind that you only need 3-bits (lines A, B, and C) so you can eliminate any parts related to the 4th bit (line D). Also note that the load pin of the 74LS161 chip is active low, so add a NOT gate in front of it.